# Mysql UPDATE with JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

Let's say I have `table1`:

```
 ID1 | COUNT 
-----------
  1  | 0 
  2  | 0
```

and `table2`:

```
 ID2 | COUNT|ID1
-----------------
  1  | 1    | 1
  2  | 2    | 2
  3  | 3    | 1
```

My goal would be get in `table1` sums of counts from `table2` grouped by ID1s, result after an `update` would be:

```
 ID1 | COUNT 
-----------
  1  | 4
  2  | 2
```

what confuses me is

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 t2 left outer join table1 t1 on t1.id1=t2.id1;
```

returns 3 rows, but

```
UPDATE table2 t2 left outer join table1 t1 on t1.id1=t2.id1
SET  t1.count=t1.count+t2.count;
```

updates just 2 rows, and produces

```
 ID1 | COUNT 
-----------
  1  | 1
  2  | 2
```

Does anyone have ideas of what the proper `update` statement would be?
P.S. I know I could do something with `SUM` but in my case `table1` has much more record than `table2`, so sums would be inefficient.

Comment: do u want to get the results as you mentioned ? or u want to update?

Comment: I want UPDATE that would leave table2 in the state I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a subquery

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET `t1.COUNT`=(SELECT SUM(`t2.COUNT`) 
  FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID1=t2.ID1)
```

It will update your whole table.

If you wanted to limit it to specific IDs then just specify them. Add:

```
WHERE t1.ID1=<some id>
```

Comment: in my case I have let's say 1M record in table1 and 100 records in table2, so the kind of update you suggesting would be undesirable

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause to the query. I added an example. If you had multiple ids you could use `IN()`

Comment: I know that would work, but that will be extremely slow in my case. I just mentioned that I do not want to use sum, but I apparently I need to confirm it again: table1 is ~5M rows, table2 is ~200K rows, join expression is ~10 fields. So even WHERE IN will be just impossibly slow.

Comment: Doing a `LEFT JOIN` is internally going to do basically the same thing. It will still be slow because MySQL will still have to examine every row.

Comment: My expectation would be MySql would be doing scan of table2 only, which would be 200K, not 5M

Comment: You have to scan table1 to find which rows to update. an `INNER JOIN` would prevent that ... but then again, so would my query when you use a `WHERE` clause on table1